# Redis - Approach for Storing Data Into Redis :: JSON String OR Serialized pojo

Tags: java, json, serialization, redis

I have a class like below:

```
   public class Person
      {
         public String name;
         public String age;
      }
```

I am a bit confused over the approach of saving a Map of Perons into Redis:

Should I go for java serialized/deserialized object approach or should i try converting to JSON and then storing and vice versa.

Any thoughts on below mentioned points:

- Cost of serialization and deserialization  VS cost of mapping to Java and to JSON
- memory Requirement for JSON and serialized object for Redis
- Compression : Stream vs Data

  Which compression should we go for
    Though DATA compression seems a bit difficult(not much benificial) as we are using Redish Hash

Some of the assumptions are:

- The pojo contain many instancd variables
- will be using Redis hash to store object

Comment: Re: Serialization cost, Java de/serialization is going to be faster. But if you use it, don't forget a ``serialVersionUID``.  Re: Memory, for very small objects (less than say 5 properties) JSON will probably be smaller, but for larger objects, Java serialization will be smaller. Warning: using Java serialization will prevent any other kind of language (Python, Ruby, Javascript, etc.) from being able to read the objects from Redis.  Despite the higher cost, I would lean toward JSON as a language-neutral format.

Comment: Yes JSON is really a good solution specially when one want to go in language neutral way. also one point i believe on serialization is that the  the size(memory required) for of a serialized object is much larger then then a JSON format as it will store the magic number classes it is storing, and all that meta info. Over slowness  benchmarks sugessts tha built in serializatio is slow. https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki

Answer (score 4):

You should consider using MessagePack as it is full compatible with Redis and Lua, it is a great compression on JSON: http://msgpack.org/

It implies some Lua code to compress and uncompress, but the cost should be small. Here is an example: http://gists.fritzy.io/2013/11/06/store-json-as-msgpack

There is a small benchmark which lacks data: https://gist.github.com/muga/1119814

Still it should be a great option for you, as you can use it in different languages, fully supported on redis, and it is based on JSON.

Comment: Even if one use MessagePack, should one consider compressing data on Network stream also so as to decrease the latency. I just went to the following link and thought of stream compression http://tech.3scale.net/2012/07/25/fun-with-redis-replication/

Comment: Middleware should not know about network compression. But you are right, if don't have a network administrator who can tune routers, switches and stuff, you will have to design some kind of compression on network in the middleware still originally it is not its responsibility. You can still use MessagePack before sending data to redis in java and it should work. Your link is interesting, LUA seems indeed the best way to limit bandwith as the function runs locally on Redis without network interaction between redis commands.

Comment: MessagePack looks interesting, we are currently using a system where we store java serialized object in redis, seeing the stats/benchmarks i am very much interested in MessagePack.

Comment: The example that you mention transforms incoming JSON into MessagePack to store it. I'm also interested in MessagePack, but wouldn't it make more sense to transfer it in MessagePack format from the client in the first place?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is you should measure it for your use cases and environment. I would first try JSON at it's more versatile and less problematic - i.e. easier to debug and restore corrupted data.

**Performance.**  JSON serialization is fast, so in many scenarios it won't be your bottleneck. Most probably it is disk or network IO: [java serialization benchmarking](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki). Avoid using default Java serialization as it is slow. [Kryo](https://code.google.com/p/kryo/) is an option for binary output. If you need miltiple platforms for binary format consider DB's internal format or i.e. Google Protobuffers.

**Compression.** In Google they use [Snappy](https://github.com/dain/snappy) for less-cpu-demanding compression. Snappy is also used in Cassandra, Hadoop and Hypertable. Some benchmarks for JVM compressors: [Compression test using Calgary corpus data set](http://ning.github.io/jvm-compressor-benchmark/results/calgary/compress-2013-06-06/index.html) .